# I have been getting this error from several sources, the latest in installing a new Canon printer

Tags: apt, updates, printing, ppa, canon

```
richard@richard-Predator-G3120:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
[sudo] password for richard: 
 
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: What are your Ubuntu version and Canon printer model?

Comment: As a more general advice: `sudo` is a command line command to execute a command as another user (often as the `root` user). It's not meant to be used in source list files. Judging from the error message, you might have something like `sudo deb https://...` instead of `deb https://...` in one or more of your source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove problematic sources list file by

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
```

Also please note that the [mentioned PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emichael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon) does not provide packages for actual Ubuntu versions, so you have to remove it using command

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:michael-gruz/canon
```

And add [other PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz) instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
```

to install relevant driver package.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the printer. Brilliant.

Comment: However, for sudo apt-get update I now get:-

Comment: E: Repository 'http://files.eid.belgium.be/debian focal InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from '' to 'focal'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
E: Repository 'http://files2.eid.belgium.be/debian focal InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from '' to 'focal'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on an Acer Predator G3120 with a Canon TS5351

Comment: Please launch Software & Updates and switch to Main Server. Then retry.

Comment: Thanks. The software & updates installer first registered internet failure. So I tried de selecting the files.eid.belgium.be/debian repos, then a lot of ubuntu updates could be loaded. After completion, I re-selected the files.eid.belgium.be/debian repos and loaded their updates. It now seems to work. No errors from sudo apt-get update.

Comment: Thank you once again

Comment: Hope that's the right tick.

Comment: Thanks, have a nice day :)